# How to break ties when using index and match

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match

Using the screenshot and formula below, I want to make a formula that is based on the points earned by a team. However, if there are ties then it will go to highest placement (where 1 is the best). Right now it lists **Team 1** twice since they are tied at 80 points with **Team 2**, but **Team 1** should be in first and **Team 2** should be in second.

**Formula** (in `P7`)**:**

`=INDEX($D$7:$D$56,MATCH($Q7,$M$7:$M$56,0))`

**Excel sheet:**
[image: excel sheet]

Comment: Why are you matching Points in the Index/Match, instead of the Placement?

Comment: @BruceWayne well the placement is what place the team comes in and the points are in the table on the left so it matches then it puts the team name in that correct slot

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below formula and helper columns

[image]

I have added Column R, S and T,

- R contains a sorted list of total points
- S contains a Tie counter to count number of same total points
- T is the actual formula that is using the R and S columns along with the column O which was already present in your sheet.
- I have added some dummy data to test the formula, you can test it on yours.
- The formula in column T is an array formula which has to be entered using Ctrl+Shift+Enter

Following are the formulas

```
R7: =LARGE($M$7:$M$13,O7)
S7: =IF(R7=R6,S6+1,1)
T7: =INDEX($D$7:$D$13,MATCH(1,($M$7:$M$13=R7)*($J$7:$J$13=SMALL(IF($M$7:$M$13=R7,$J$7:$J$13),S7)),0))
```